# Is eqnarray really obsolete?

Tags: equations, amsmath, obsolete

I just learned in [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) that `eqnarray` should be avoided in general. Ok, so I started looking at my documents to get rid of it and (as suggested) use some environment of the `amsmath` package instead. However, I encountered two situations where this change yields a worse output (IMHO) than with `eqnarray`. This may be due to my lack of knowledge how to do it right, but first I will show the two situations:

The first one is a sequence of (in-)equalities used to prove a bound (as common in, e.g., runtime complexity analysis). This one here is used to show that 2^n does not grow faster than n!.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
2^n & =                      & \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{=}    & 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      & 16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & <                      & 24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      & 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{\leq} & 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n\\
    & =                      & n!
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

It yields the following output:

[image]

These are my attempts to use some environment of the `amsmath` package instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
2^n & =                      \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{=}    2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & <                      24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{\leq} 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n\\
    & =                      n!
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{aligned}
2^n & =                      && \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{=}    && 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      && 16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & <                      && 24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      && 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{\leq} && 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n\\
    & =                      && n!
\end{aligned}
\]

\begin{alignat*}{2}
2^n & =                      && \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{=}    && 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      && 16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & <                      && 24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      && 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{n > 3}{\leq} && 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n\\
    & =                      && n!
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding outputs have the following flaws:

- `align`:

[image]

The reduced space between the relation symbols and the terms they connect makes it harder to recognize the steps in this proof. While one can argue whether more space is a good thing here (I read "consistency over all" in one of the documents advocating the avoidance of `eqnarray` and I do not entirely agree on this - I think readability is more important than consistency while consistency supports readability in most cases but possibly not always), I think it is definitely not the best thing that the relations built with `\stackrel` are not aligned in a centered way below the other relation symbols. The latter point is also a flaw of all the other attempts to use an environment of the `amsmath` package (which is to be expected as these environments only offer columns being left- or right-aligned but not centered - at least I did not find a similar environment offering a centered column).

- `aligned`:

[image]

While we do have more space on the right of the relation symbols, we have less space on the left of them.

- `alignat`:

[image]

This is even worse than `aligned` since now the spacing is not only different between left and right of the relation symbols but we also have almost no space between the relation symbols built with `\stackrel` and the next term.

The second situation is the definition of substitutions as comma-separated lists of replacements in square brackets (a notation quite common in, e.g., term rewriting or logic programming). If these definitions are too long such that we need to break them, the environments of the `amsmath` package do not succeed in aligning the second line correctly while keeping the same amount of space left and right of the `=` symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma & = & [x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
       &   & x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{align*}
\sigma & = [x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
       &   x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
\sigma & = [x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
       &   x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{split}
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{aligned}
\sigma & = && [x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
       &   && x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{aligned}
\]

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\sigma & = && [x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
       &   && x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

- `eqnarray`:

[image]

- `align`:

[image]

Here, the two versions with and without the use of `split` yield the same output. The spacing around `=` is consistent but the alignment of the second line is wrong.

- `aligned`:

[image]

Here, the alignment is ok, but the spacing is inconsistent.

- `alignat`:

[image]

Again, the alignment is ok but the spacing is inconsistent.

So my question is: How can these two situations be handled without using `eqnarray` yielding an output which is at least as readable as the versions using it and with a similar (or less) amount of code?

Of course, one can use `array` and customize it accordingly, but what would be the point of doing so in preference of using the existing `eqnarray`? Also, in [Aligning a split up equation not at equal sign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116585/aligning-a-split-up-equation-not-at-equal-sign) (which is similar to my second situation) the only answer suggests to use `\phantom` in combination with `align` to fix the alignment. While this is of course possible, it is definitely more tedious than using `eqnarray` in such a situation as described above.

Comment: “Solving” the bad alignment with `eqnarray` is wrong anyway, because `eqnarray` must ***never*** be used: its output is bad and it doesn't cooperate well with some packages (notably `hyperref` and `cleveref`).

Comment: @egreg Well, here I show a case where I consider the output with `eqnarray` better than that of `align` (at least in the form I tried to use it). My question is not to improve the output of the versions using `eqnarray` but to come up with alternatives that do **not** use it and yield an output which is at least as good. I understand that there are many problems with `eqnarray` but avoiding it just for the sake of avoiding it does not make sense to me. In these situations described here, I do not have any problems with `hyperref` or `cleveref` or whatsoever.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The output of `eqnarray` is wrong anyway and there's little to do about it. Consider also that it doesn't work with cross-references if `hyperref` or `cleveref` are involved.

No, there's no reason for using it.

The first example can be dealt with using `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}} c <{{}} @{} l @{} }
2^n
 & =                   & \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}}\\
 & \overset{n>3}{=}    & 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
 & =                   & 16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
 & <                   & 24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
 & =                   & 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
 & \overset{n>3}{\leq} & 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n\\
 & =                   & n!
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

A better proof, by induction, is
\begin{alignat*}{2}
2^4     &= 16 < 4! = 24  \\
2^{n+1} &= 2\cdot 2^n    &\quad&\text{for $n>3$} \\
        &< 2\cdot n!     &\quad&\text{induction hypothesis}\\
        &< (n+1)\cdot n! \\
        &= (n+1)!
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example is even easier: use a good alignment point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sigma =[ &x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
          & x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More lines can be accommodated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sigma = [ &x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2, \\
           & x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4] \\
\tau   = [ &y_1/t_1] \\
\psi   = [ &x_1/t_1,x_2/t_2,\\
           & x_3/t_3,x_4/t_4]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the advantage of using `array` instead of `eqnarray`? Which problems are solved/avoided doing so? Concerning the second situation: What if I have several substitutions and would like to align these on the = symbol, but only some must be broken?

Comment: @cryingshadow Look closely at the output, you'll see that the spacing is much better with `array`. About the second problem, I see no issue, I'll add the example.

Comment: I see that there is less space around the relation symbols but why is that better? Is it more consistent in any place (then please point me to the details)? Moreover, the settings for `array` seem much more complicated than just taking the existing `eqnarray` environment. Just for the sake of having less space around the relation symbols, I would not consider this a good trade-off. Is there any additional benefit?

Comment: Ah, I agree on the second situation, but for the first I would still like to know what the actual advantage of `array` over `eqnarray` is.

Comment: @cryingshadow I see no advantage whatsoever in using `eqnarray`. Do as you like.

Comment: Compare the amount of code. There is definitely less code in the version using `eqnarray` compared to yours with `array`. I would consider the output in both versions more or less equally good. Don't get me wrong: I do not want to use `eqnarray` if there is an actual advantage in not doing so. But just changing a document to avoid the use of `eqnarray` if there is no advantage would mean work for nothing. So I'm asking what the advantage in avoiding `eqnarray` in favor of `array` is such that this change is justified.

Comment: @cryingshadow Don't get me wrong. I think that egreg already give you the best answer "Do as you like" so if you like `eqnarray` just use it and if you change your mind later, just change your code.

Comment: @touhami No worries - this is no flamewar and I don't see a reason why it should become one. ;) The thing is that "as you like" sounds very opinion-based while I would like to know if there is an objective reason in the situation above not to use `eqnarray` apart from "Thou shalt not use `eqnarray`!" ;)

Comment: @cryingshadow I tried to explain that `eqnarray` provides bad output, is buggy and incompatible with useful packages. If these are insufficient reasons for you, I don't know what else to say.

Comment: @cryingshadow may be here https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf

Comment: @egreg These three points are certainly true in many cases. But in the particular situation here I see none of them. The output is fine as it is, I do not get any errors and there are no incompatibilities *in this particular situation* (I'm using both `hyperref` and and `cleveref` in the same document where such a sequence of transformations is contained). Apart from that I see the (small) advantage of slightly less code. So could this situation be seen as the exception to the rule or is even in this situation an objective reason to change the code and use `array` instead of `eqnarray`?

Comment: @touhami I read this article (it's actually the one where it is said "Consistency above all" (p. 5)). It definitely explains well why `eqnarray` should be avoided in *many* cases. However, for my *particular* situation I still do not see a convincing argument there as equations are usually seen as stand-alone objects in this article and not as proof steps. I think it is ok that "real equations" and "proof steps" are distinguishable by different spacing. This does not automatically mean inconsistency IMHO.

Comment: @egreg To overcome the "amount of code" problem, one might add a command like `\newcommand{\inarray}[1]{{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\[\begin{array}{@{} r @{\;} >{{}} c <{{}} @{\;} l @{}}#1\end{array}\]\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}}`. Could you add something similar to your answer?

Answer (score 7):

Use `\mathclap`:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\begin{document}
\begingroup 
\advance\thickmuskip by 5mu  % 5mu = 5/18 em
\begin{align*}
    2^n &=                      \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n \text{ 
    times}}\\
    & \stackrel{\mathclap{n > 3}}{=}    2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot \underbrace{2 
    \cdot 2 \cdot 
    \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      16 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 
    \text{ times}}\\
    & <                      24 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 
    \text{ times}}\\
    & =                      1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 
    \ldots \cdot 2}_{n - 4 \text{ times}}\\
    & \stackrel{\mathclap{n > 3}}{\leq} 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots 
    \cdot n\\
    & =                      n!
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the part `\advance\thickmuskip by 5mu` about? Is this generally applicable or tailored to the content above the relation symbols?

Comment: It is in mathmode the space left and right from the relation symbol `=`. `1mu=1/18 em`