# Nice display of proof steps without eqnarray

Tags: math-mode, equations

This is a follow-up question to: [Is eqnarray really obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete)

The background is that I want to follow the general advice to [avoid `eqnarray`](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf). However, while working on old documents still containing `eqnarray` (here, my use case is working on the conference version of a paper when preparing an extended version for a journal), I encountered two situations in my previous question linked above where I did not find an obvious way to obtain an output that had at least the same quality as when using `eqnarray` but using different environments like `align`. For the first of these two situations (namely a sequence of proof steps where equations are successively applied to a term), one answer suggested to use `array` instead of `eqnarray` while the other answer suggested using a combination of `align` and `\mathclap`. However, here I have another problem when using either solution to replace the use of `eqnarray`. The following code contains 5 versions of the same sequence of proof steps, the first using `eqnarray`, the second and third using the first suggested solution from the previous question, and the fourth and fifth the second suggested solution from the previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y,z) & =                                   & \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & =                                   & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition1})}{=} & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition2})}{=} & 42
\end{eqnarray*}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\[\begin{array}{@{} r @{\;} >{{}} c <{{}} @{\;} l @{}}
f(x,y,z) & =                                   & \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & =                                   & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition1})}{=} & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition2})}{=} & 42
\end{array}\]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\[\begin{array}{@{} r @{\;} >{{}} c <{{}} @{\;} l @{}}
f(x,y,z) & =                                   & \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & =                                   & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition1})}{=} & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition2})}{=} & 42
\end{array}\]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}

\begingroup 
\advance\thickmuskip by 5mu
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) & = \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & = \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{\mathclap{(\mathit{condition1})}}{=} \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{\mathclap{(\mathit{condition2})}}{=} 42
\end{align*}
\endgroup

\begingroup 
\advance\thickmuskip by 30mu
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) & = \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & = \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{\mathclap{(\mathit{condition1})}}{=} \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{\mathclap{(\mathit{condition2})}}{=} 42
\end{align*}
\endgroup

$(\mathit{condition1})$ holds since the sky is red and $(\mathit{condition2})$ because this is the answer.

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:

- `eqnarray`:

[image]

- `array`:

[image]

- `array` with higher stretch factor:

[image]

- `align`:

[image]

- `align` with higher `\thickmuskip`:

[image]

The problems in this example are the following:

- The relation symbols used in each step may have a different horizontal length but should be aligned below each other in a centered way. Therefore, the usual AMS environments do not work in an obvious way since they only offer left- or right-aligned columns. The second solution tries to overcome this problem by using `\mathclap`, but then the space between the relation symbols and everything else must be adjusted manually (as seen in the last version).
- When using `array`, the vertical space between each line is "set" manually by adjusting the value of `\arraystretch`. While in the previous question a value of `1.5` was "the right" value, here the same value leads to overlapping lines. So with the first solution, the vertical space needs to be adjusted manually for each case separately.
- Another problem when using `array` is that the fractions seem to be compressed.

Is there a way to achieve an output of at least the quality of version 1 without the need to manually adjust values for different cases of such proof step sequences and without using `eqnarray`?

Comment: I honestly think there is very little need for placing content above the `=`. I think you can get an equally clear presentation (if not better, since the spacing is consistent) using [this layout](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPz8T.png)...

Comment: @Werner True, but what if the whole thing needs all the space of the textwidth? The variant over the `=` symbols saves some space in such cases.

Comment: Then, instead of placing a "huge" `(condition1)` or `(condition2)` over `=`, I'll use `(1)` or `(2)` and describe that after the entire construction.

Comment: @Werner, True again. But what happens if you have more than 10 such things? And don't tell me that the proof is too complicated if it needs more than 10 steps (which is probably also true but finding shorter and still clear proofs is definitely a very hard problem)... ;)

Comment: You will probably always find a "but..." based on a counter-suggestion... You seem to be convinced that `eqnarray` is still a hidden hero. Go for it then.

Comment: @Werner No, I definitely see the reasons why `eqnarray` should generally be avoided. The story written here is true: I tried to remove `eqnarray` but stumbled over this situation (of course with a bigger and more meaningful example). I would actually be happy if there was an easy way of solving such things - then I would not need to worry whether any of the problems with `eqnarray` like incompatibilities will cause a problem sooner or later when I continue to work with such things...

Comment: @Werner I just tried your suggestion with (1) instead of longer things. Even with (1) there is already a tiny shift of the symbols.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, `eqnarray` has so many limitations that even being forced to do some tricks has its advantages. For instance, `eqnarray` can *never* be broken across pages, whereas your proof steps might be so long that a page break could become necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\alignedrel}[2]{%
  \Cen{2}{\overset{#1}{#2}{}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Cen}[2]{% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209732/4427
  \ifmeasuring@
    #2%
  \else
    \makebox[\ifcase\expandafter #1\maxcolumn@widths\fi][c]{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x,y,z)
  & \alignedrel{}{=}
      && \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
  & \alignedrel{}{=}
      && \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
  & \alignedrel{\text{(condition1)}}{=}
      && \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
  & \alignedrel{\text{(condition2)}}{=}
      && 42
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The pagebreaks are a good point. However, this seems to be problematic with other environments as well. I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51682/is-it-possible-to-pagebreak-aligned-equations and it says pagebreaks are only possible with `align` and `gather`. Is `alignat` mandatory for your solution? Is there a way to break a page in `alignat` (maybe a follow-up question if the answer is not simply "no")?

Comment: I'd rather use `\intertext{condition/explanation}` as they become natual break points. In writing comments like this does not belon on top of relations etc. You might do this on a blackboard, but not in typeset text

Comment: @cryingshadow Well, that comment didn't tell the full truth and is gone. Be happy: also `alignat` is breakable. My typographic choice would of course be setting the conditions on the side, not above the equals signs.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than overburden some of the `=` symbols with too much information, I would recommend that you provide a normal-language sentence *after* the group of equations to explain, *in words*, why the final two equalities hold.

Oh, and I would definitely use an `align*` environment, not an `eqnarray*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) 
&= \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
&= \floor*{\frac{\frac{x/z}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}}\\
&= \floor*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c/a}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}}\\
&= 42.
\end{align*}
The second-to-last equality follows because the sky is red (Condition~1), and the final equality holds because it is the answer (Condition~2).

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: If you have relation symbols that have different widths, e.g., `=` and `\hookrightarrow`, you could still use an *align* environment, by reversing the order of the relation symbols and the `&` symbols, as is shown in the following example. (The `{}` particle are there to get the right amount of spacing.)

```
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) 
={}& \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
={}& \floor*{\frac{\frac{x/z}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}}\\
\hookrightarrow{}& \floor*{\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c/a}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}}\\
={}& 42.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Okay, then suppose that I have different relation symbols with a different width (e.g. `\hookrightarrow` and `=` - this is what happened in one of my real examples). I think your solution only works if I have relation symbols of equal width. Is that true?

Comment: Ah, never mind the `\hookrightarrow` one - that was only due to strange mode changes. In normal math mode, this would work.

Comment: @cryingshadow -- I've posted an addendum to my answer, to show how you might handle relation symbols of varying widths.

Comment: So the "solution" is basically to avoid not only `eqnarray` but also `\stackrel` (at least in this combination). Since with `\stackrel`, your solution would probably have the same problems that I had in the previous question (true?). While I would still be interested in a solution that allows to use `\stackrel`, your answer at least allows me to work around my current issue (although that means tiny changes to the content). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, but here I have another mean one (I guess I had evil things in this paper...): What if I have something like `=_D`? Even with your addendum, this gets "shifted" a bit.

Comment: @cryingshadow - Something like `=_D` should pose no difficulty; with the method set forth in the addendum, just write `=_D{}&`. (Aside: I have no idea what `=_D` might mean, but presumably your readers do, right?) A separate matter: If you find yourself having to provide derivations of results that involve a multitude of different relational operators, you may want to rethink from scratch how you should be going about showing your results.

Comment: These different "relations" are often different kinds of evaluations (e.g. in term rewriting when different rewrite systems or evaluation strategies are used - that's also why different kinds of arrows are involved). This is quite common in the respective field.

Comment: @cryingshadow - How about (a) writing `\stackrel{A}{=}`, `\stackrel{A}{=}`, `\stackrel{C}{=}`, etc in equations and (b) explaining somewhere in the document what these special equality relations mean?

Comment: This goes in a similar direction as @Werner's suggestion. This would be another workaround (it seems A is small enough to not increase the width of the = symbol). Still, from a technical point of view, I would be interested whether the original example could also be displayed as intended under the given constraints.

Answer (score 3):

some possibilities

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength\mylength
\begin{document}

eqnarray
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y,z) & =                                   & \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & =                                   & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition1})}{=} & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition2})}{=} & 42
\end{eqnarray*}

array in display
{\setlength\extrarowheight{10pt}
\[\begin{array}{@{} >\displaystyle r @{\;} 
>{\displaystyle{}} c <{{}} @{\;}
>\displaystyle l @{}}
f(x,y,z) & =                                   & \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & =                                   & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition1})}{=} & \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \stackrel{(\mathit{condition2})}{=} & 42
\end{array}\]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}



align
\begingroup 
\settowidth\mylength{$\scriptstyle(\mathit{condition2})$}
\newcommand\condeq[1]{\stackrel{\makebox[\mylength]{$\scriptstyle#1$}}{=}}
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) & \condeq{} \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & \condeq{} \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \condeq{(\mathit{condition1})} \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor\\
         & \condeq{(\mathit{condition2})} 42
\end{align*}
\endgroup

$(\mathit{condition1})$ holds since the sky is red and $(\mathit{condition2})$ because this is the answer.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would add a `\scriptsize` directive to the argument of `\makebox`, ie., write `\newcommand\condeq[1]{\stackrel{\makebox[6em]{\scriptsize$#1$}}{=}}`.

Comment: Would it be possible to "infer" the correct length for the `\makebox` instead of manually specifying it?

Comment: @cryingshadow answer updated

Comment: @Mico sorry missed your comment, was driving:-) In the update I did `$\scriptsyle...` which is similar.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it allowed in the UK to drive and solve LaTeX problems at the same time? ;)

Comment: @cryingshadow in my head I solve all kinds of problems while driving, unfortunately the real world does not always fit to my mental model though.

Answer (score 1):

For information. You can try `witharrows`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{DispWithArrows*}
f(x,y,z) & = \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}\\
         & = \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y}+\frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}\right\rfloor
           \Arrow{condition 1} \\
         & = \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}{\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}\right\rfloor
           \Arrow{condition 2} \\
         & = 42
\end{DispWithArrows*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

To my best effort I don't understand your intention. To invent new form how to write solution depend on some condition? For selection one of solution regarding to some condition`amsmath` and `mathtools` provide environments `cases` and `dcases` respectively:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(x,y,z) 
    & = \frac{g(x,y,z)}{h(x,y,z)}       \\
    & = \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\frac{x}{z}}{y} + 
                    \frac{y}{z}}{\frac{z}{y} + \frac{y}{x}}
        \right\rfloor                   \\
    & = \begin{dcases}
            \left\lfloor
                \frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{b}}
                     {\frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a}}
            \right\rfloor       &\quad   \text{condition 1} \\
            42                  &\quad   \text{condition 2} 
        \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
$(\mathit{condition1})$ holds since the sky is red and $(\mathit{condition2})$ because this is the answer.
    \end{document}
```

[image]

If you only look how to align right side of equations at different width of relations between left and right side of equations, than the result without some manual tweaking always will not look nice (according to different taste of people).

Comment: No, I think this is a misunderstanding. The last two steps in the example should be "explained" by condition1 and condition2 (i.e., these steps hold because these conditions are true). There should not be a case analysis as with `cases`. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: If you say so. However, I still believe that your approach lead to notation which is very difficult to understand a math meaning as well is typographical very ugly. Different people, different tastes ... :-)

Comment: Well, this notation is not my invention. But you're definitely right that it is a matter of taste whether this notation is considered beautiful or ugly. Actually, this kind of notation was the first form for such proof sequences that was introduced to me. So I'm quite used to it and never questioned its look from a more distant perspective. It's interesting for me that so many people seem to find this notation awkward and I will definitely think about alternatives (nevertheless, from a technical point of view I find the question here still interesting whether it is just possible).