# how to use mathbf or bold type in eqnarray environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, boldmath

my math equations dosent look very clear, i think they lack a little of bold.

how can i use `\mathbf` in `eqnarray` environment ?

more general what do you suggest to make equations very clear and visible ?

Comment: You should not use `eqnarray`, that's outdated. Use `align` and the related environments. And don't ask more than one question in one post

Comment: Note: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete

Comment: note that \mathbf does not give you a bold version of the existing equation, it gives upright roman bold (often changing the meaning) to make all math bold use `\boldmath` before the mathematics

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= \mathbf{b}\\
c &= \mathbf{d}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Making equations look nice is a subjective issue (I never use bold unless I am playing with matrices and capital letters). But in any case, avoid `eqnarray` that has documented problems.

[image]