# Strange \cref bug

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I'm using `cleverref` in my document. Unfortunately I'm receiving some strange bugs. By referring to equation `\label{eg:hey}`, I'm writing `\cref{eq:hey}` and get `equation (1,1)`. Often that results in equation, but sometimes it bugs and turns itself into `section 1.1.1`.

Any ideas why? Ive checked and doubled/triplechecked that I don't have any multiple defined references.

My reference code:

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,citecolor = title,linkcolor = title,urlcolor = title}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\creflabelformat{figure}{\color{tudelft-dark-blue} \textbf{#1#2#3}}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\creflabelformat{table}{\color{tudelft-dark-blue} \textbf{#1#2#3}}
\crefname{table}{table}{table}
\creflabelformat{equation}{[#1#2#3]}
\creflabelformat{equation}{\color{tudelft-dark-blue}(#1#2#3)}
\crefname{equation}{\color{tudelft-dark-blue}equation}{equations}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{eq. #3[#1]#4--#5[#2]#6}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{equation #3#1#4--#5#2#6}
```

My code:

```
 \cref{eq:K1}
\begin{eqnarray}
K_1 &=&\sigma_n Y\sqrt{\pi a}\label{eq:K1}
\end{eqnarray}
```

The result:

[image]

My result by changing `\cref` into `\ref`

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Looks like you're right... the bug disappears if i change the math env to equation.. Thank you Torbjørn

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not really `\cref`, but that you're using `eqnarray`. `eqnarray` is known to have problems with several things, and should not be used. See e.g.

- [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)
- [Is eqnarray really obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete)
- [Which command should I use for displayed equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/)

For the equation you show, there is no alignment needed anyway, which is another reason for not using `eqnarray`: Use `equation` instead.

As mentioned in some of the linked questions, use the environments provided by `amsmath` instead of `eqnarray`.

Minimal example showing the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}    
\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
\cref{a,b}
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathit{wrong} \label{a}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{equation}
\mathit{right} \label{b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Torbjørn T. says it's best to avoid `eqnarray` really however (stealing the MWE) if you really need to use it you can give `\cref` a bit of help to pick up the `equation` counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}    
\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
\cref{a,b}
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathit{wrong}
%set up \label for \cref
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}
\label{a}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{equation}
\mathit{right} \label{b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```