# eqnarray and \cref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

\cref{equation label} is showing section number instead of equation number -

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}




\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\title{Your Paper}

\author{You}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle





\section{AAA}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:87}
    as+56=09
\end{equation}
\section{BBBB}
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:hjk}
6+09=2455 
\end{eqnarray}

\cref{eq:87}
\cref{eq:hjk}





\end{document}
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or advice on how to overcome this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[image: The output is shown in the attached image.]

Comment: Read the manual of the package **cleveref**, section 14.1. It says: ***Cleveref** will not work properly with the standard LaTeX **eqnarray** environment. There is no intention to fix this. The **eqnarray** environment is poorly implemented*. The author suggest to use **gather**, **align**, **multline** and **split** from **amsmath** in replacement for **eqnarray**.

Comment: If you really need using **eqnarray**, you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339759/132405) a workaround, by David Carlisle.

Comment: @quark67 Thanks alot.

Comment: @quark67 ooh I didn't remember that:-)