# How to line up around equal sign with right align in same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{float}  

\begin{eqnarray*}  
8+4-3*2&=&x (1)    
8+4-6&=&x (2)    
12-6&=&x (3)  
x&=&6 (4)  
\end{eqnarray*}
```

[This is how I want the document to look, but I cannot figure out how to align the numbers (1,2,3,4) on the right on the same line as the equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j44Ro.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE! Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285226/52406) about `eqnarray`.

Comment: remove all the numbers in brackets and remove the `*` so the equations are numbered automatocally

Comment: If you want to set the numbers manually, you can reset the counter before the `eqnarray` (`\setcounter{equation}{0}`). If you don't want to use numbers, use `\tag{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use  `eqnarray`  as it produces bad spacing around the alignment point. Use`align` from `amsmath`, which further more has a simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
8+4-3*2 &= x \\
8+4-6 &= x \\
12-6&= x \\
x &= 6
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]