# csvReader eqnarray Problem

Tags: math-mode, equations, missing, eqnarray

I use eqnarray for equations. After using csvreader, the "special" mathematical symbols like "sum" disappear.

The following is the code. The equation before and after csvreader is the same.

```
    \begin{eqnarray}
0 & = & \sum_{t=1}^{n} (E_{t} - A_{t}) * (1+r)^{-t} + L_{n} (1+r)^{-n} - A_{0}
\end{eqnarray}


\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \csvreader[separator=semicolon, respect and, tabular=|l||*{13}{r|},
table head=\hline& Jan & Feb & Mrz & Apr & Mai & Jun & Jul & Aug & Sep & Okt & Nov & Dez & Summe\\\hline\hline,
late after line=\\\hline]%
{DATA/KVN/kvnmonat.csv}{artikel=\artikel,1=\jan,2=\feb,3=\mrz,4=\apr,5=\mai,6=\jun,7=\jul,8=\aug,9=\sep,10=\okt,11=\nov,12=\dez,Summe=\sum}%
{\artikel&\jan&\feb&\mrz&\apr&\mai&\jun&\jul&\aug&\sep&\okt&\nov&\dez&\sum}%
    }
\caption[Anzahl der bei KVN gebauten Displays]
{\label{tab:kvndisplaykomm} Menge der bei KVN gebauten Displays unterteilt nach Monaten und Display.}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\begin{eqnarray}
0 & = & \sum_{t=1}^{n} (E_{t} - A_{t}) * (1+r)^{-t} + L_{n} (1+r)^{-n} - A_{0}
\end{eqnarray}
```

After Compiling it looks like this:

[image: Before and after csvreader]

The Sum-Symbol is missing from now on in the whole document, in all chapters.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe change `Summe=\sum` to `Summe=\summe` and change the table accordingly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `I use eqnarray for equations`. Well, you shouldn't, see [Avoid eqnarray](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/). This being said, could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: @TeXnician that was great work man! Thank you. Now it works. That was the problem. I wasn´t even aware of my usage of the same variable. Thank you, Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at your assignments you will notice that you use `\sum`:

```
{artikel=\artikel,1=\jan,2=\feb,3=\mrz,4=\apr,5=\mai,6=\jun,7=\jul,8=\aug,9=\sep,10=\okt,11=\nov,12=\dez,Summe=\sum}
```

This overwrites the `\sum` macro with every item read. Hence `\sum` will not work in math mode (at least not the way you expect it to work).

Changing the variable name will solve the problem.

Just a comment: You should not use `eqnarray` for equations, because it is [obsolete](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete).

Comment: Yes, for internal reasons, `csvsimple` does *global* assignments to the variables; it's better to use uncommon names, for instance with all capital letters.