# Using numcases in eqnarray

Tags: numbering

Can anyone show how to use eqnarray and numcases together? The example below works fine without numcases, but I would like to number the equations in the cases separately.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=& \Theta(x) \\
&=&\begin{cases}
1, & x > 0\\
 0 , & x < 0
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please complete your code, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please note that the use of `eqnarray` is deprecated. It is preferable to use `amsmath` package macros as `equation` for instance. Have a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285226/is-eqnarray-really-obsolete) for more information

Answer (score 3):

Very *ad hoc* solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \Theta(x) \\
     &  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-1.6ex}[0pt][0pt]{${}=\bigg\lbrace$}}
        \hspace{2.25em}\makebox[2em][l]{$1$,}  x > 0\\
     &  \hspace{2.25em}\makebox[2em][l]{$0$,}  x < 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]